# npm not found from Visual Studio code terminal but is verified from a Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

When I try to run "npm" from VS Code terminal, I get the error "The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Now, when using Command Prompt and navigated to the project folder, I verify that node.js is installed and from the command prompt I verify that npm is installed.

However, when in VSCode terminal window, neither node.js nor npm is found to be installed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

no. same problem here. tryed npm install -g npm but get same error.
I thought I had installed nodeJs here but it seems not.
Close VS Code. Probably must install NodeJs LTS.
Open VS Code again and try it.

Comment: yes, Just restart VS code

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem before. Here is a list of potential solutions:

1. Make sure your terminal opens up in your project folder. Sometimes when we open our project or the terminal in visual studio, we are not directly in the right folder. Use the command `cd projectName` in the terminal to navigate
2. Did you run the `npm install -g npm` command in your project's terminal?

   If so, use `node -v` and `npm -v` to check versions.
   If not, run the command `npm install -g npm` in your project's terminal
3. Try reinstalling npm with the `npm install -g npm`